# Confusion over the definition of disjoint union

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

From Wikipedia, the disjoint union of some sets, $\uplus A_i$, is a set $A$ with an injective function for each $A_i$ to $A$, such that the union of the images of these functions forms a partitions of $A$.

But the union of some sets is just a single set, whereas a partition is a set of sets, so what does it mean for this single set to "form a partition" of $A$?

From the Wikipedia example, for the sets $A_0=\{5,6,7\}$ and $A_1=\{5,6\}$ it gives the disjoint union as $A=\{(5,0),(6,0),(7,0),(5,1),(5,2)\}$ with the injective function for each $A_i$ as $f(x)=(x,i)$. Unless I'm mistaken, the union of the images of these functions is just $A$ itself, right? But $A$ is not a partition of $A$ - even for the $n=1$ case the partition would be $\{A\}$ rather than just $A$. So how is "the union of the images of the functions forms a partition of $A$" true?

Comment: There is a typo in your set $A$: the final $(5,2)$ should be $(6,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the union of these images is $A$, so that is maybe poorly phrased. What they mean is that the images of these injections partition $A$. That is
$$
P = \{ f_i(A_i) : 0 \leq i < n \}
$$
partitions $A = \biguplus_{0 \leq i < n} A_i$, where $f_i: A_i \to A$ is the injection corresponding to $0 \leq i < n$.

So in your example we have $n = 2$ and so
$$
P = \{f_0(A_0), f_1(A_1)\} = \{\{(5,0), (6,0), (7,0)\}, \{(5,1), (6,1)\}\},
$$
which is indeed a partition of
$$
A=\{(5,0),(6,0),(7,0),(5,1),(6,1)\}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

What that article says is just that the images $f(A_0)$ and $f(A_1)$ form a partition of $A$, which means
$$
A=f(A_0)\cup f(A_1)
$$
and $f(A_0)\cup f(A_1)=\emptyset$.

The phrase "the union of the images of these functions" should be understood as the *collection* of the images of these functions.